# SetResponsePage in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket, html

I saw that there are two ways to set a responsePage in Wicket's WebPage:

```
 setResponsePage(new MyPage());
```

or

```
 setResponsePage(MyPage.class);
```

What are the differences between these two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first one will redirect to a bookmarkable URL.

Please see also the [Wicket FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/FAQs#FAQs-WhatisthedifferencebetweensetResponsePage%28newMyWebPage%28%29%29andsetResponsePage%28MyWebPage.class%29).

Comment: Either way, Wicket redirects me to a bookmarkable URL. Does the page need a special constructor to redirect to a non-bookmarkable URL?

Answer (score 2):

Wicket's doc sais it best:

"setResponsePage(new MyWebPage()) (or setResponsePage(new MyWebPage(myPageParameters))) can be used if you want to have a bookmarkable url in the browser (your page must have default constructor or PageParameter constructor).
setResponsePage(MyWebPage.class) can be used if you want to pass information to pages on the serverside. This generates a session specific url (most of the time you can use hybrid url coding strategy)."

[here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/faqs.html#FAQs-WhatisthedifferencebetweensetResponsePage%28newMyWebPage%28%29%29andsetResponsePage%28MyWebPage.class%29)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you can send parameters to .setResponsePage(new [WebPage](http://javadox.com/org.apache.wicket/wicket-core/1.5.7/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/WebPage.html)(p1,p2,p3)) and in `.setResponsePage(WebPage.class)` you can't.

If you mount a page, `.setResponsePage([WebPage.class])`[2](http://javadox.com/org.apache.wicket/wicket-core/1.5.7/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/WebPage.html) will send a user to the url you defined in the `WicketApplication`, when you mounted the page doing something like:

```
public void init() {

this.mountPage("/myPage", **WebPage.class**)


}
```

Comment: I think you are wrong: Component's setResponsePage has both interfaces, setResponsePage(java.lang.Class<C> cls) as well as setResponsePage(java.lang.Class<C> cls, PageParameters parameters). There is no need to call new WebPage to add page parameters.