# All of my pages are mounted as bookmarkable pages

Tags: wicket

All of my pages in my application (wicket 1.5.3) are rendered with a bookmarkable url. It doesn't matter if I call the page with `setResponsePage(new Page())` or `setResponsePage(Page.class)`.

My classes just have a standard non-arg constructor.

Following these documentation:

> Non-bookmarkable pages have default constructors and constructors with the PageParameters argument hidden (protected/private), or none at all. It could have any other constructor, like MyPage(FooClass bar) etc. The net effect of your page being non-bookmarkable is that there is no way a user can directly access your page. So, by making a page non-bookmarkable, you make it a 'safe' page.

my pages should not be bookmarkable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See org.apache.wicket.settings.ISecuritySettings#setEnforceMounts(boolean).

Answer (score 0):

Are you mounting any of your pages in your WebApplication class?

Comment: yes, several, but of course not the ones I do not want bookmarkable

Comment: can u give an example of a setResponsePage(new Page()) your calling and the url its producing. Also are your using anything like PackageMounting?

Comment: No package mounting. `setResponsePage(Objectdata.class);` leads to this --> `http://localhost:8080/wicket/bookmarkable/com.johndoe.Objectdata?4`

Comment: and if you use setResponsePage(new Objectdata()) u get the same?

Comment: Now I get a non-bookmarkable URL! Strange. I remember having it changed somewhere else without a difference. Also the offical doc says: `setResponsePage(new MyWebPage()) (or setResponsePage(new MyWebPage(myPageParameters))) can be used if you want to have a bookmarkable url in the browser (your page must have default constructor or PageParameter constructor).
setResponsePage(MyWebPage.class) can be used if you want to pass information to pages on the serverside. This generates a session specific url (most of the time you can use hybrid url coding strategy).`

Comment: I don't know why this behavior is inverted.

Comment: For non-bookmarkable URL i always use setResponsePage(new MyWebPage()), but can get bookmarkable page from setResponsePage(new MyWebPage()) if that page is mounted.

Comment: The behavior is clear when the page is mounted. But otherwise you shouldn't get a bookmarkable page, see also this question on so: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849328/setresponsepage-in-wicket/8849434](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849328/setresponsepage-in-wicket/8849434)